# Scalebase feedback (or other tool, spiderdb ...)

Tags: database, scalability, web-crawler, sharding

have you ever tested scalebase or a shard facility in production?
If yes, could you make a feedback (theory vs practice)?

I look at some other techno like spiderdb and so on...

I like the solutions based on MySQL

J

Comment: We are using sharding in production with MySQL. What do you want to hear exactly?